# Parallel Programming in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am interested in running the same function that does some monte carlo evaluations with different values of the arguments on mulitple kernels in a parallel fashion. I also want to ensure that entire function runs on the same kernel, without the computations within the function being distributed across kernels. For example, suppose I have a function (deliberately simplified)

```
f[a_, b_] := Module[{}, RandomReal[{a, b}]]


In[1]:= LaunchKernels[]

Out[1]= {KernelObject[1, "local"], KernelObject[2, "local"], 
 KernelObject[3, "local"], KernelObject[4, "local"], 
 KernelObject[5, "local"], KernelObject[6, "local"], 
 KernelObject[7, "local"]}

SeedRandom[795132, Method -> "ParallelGenerator"];

m1 = 1; m2 = 2; m3 = 3; m4 = 4; m5 = 5; m6 = 6; m7 = 7; m8 = 8;

DistributeDefinitions[f, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8];
```

I now want to run f[m1, m2], f[m3, m4], f[m5, m6], f[m7, m8] f[m9, m10] on five different kernels with no information transfer across these kernels, i.e, with a separate stream of random numbers across the different kernels.

How can one do this within Mathematica?

Comment: Have fun guys, I am sitting this one out.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It's no fun when you're not around to compete with though :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can seed individual kernels with `$KernelID` and `$ProcessID`?

```
ParallelEvaluate[
 Print[$KernelID $ProcessID];
 SeedRandom[$KernelID $ProcessID]
]
```

And this should go to five different kernels (the FinestGrained option takes every evaluation to a new kernel):

```
ParallelTable[$KernelID -> f[2 i - 1, 2 i], {i, 5}, Method -> "FinestGrained"]
```

When `i` (max 5) is greater than the number of kernels (8), this is going to run into issues though, i.e. `f[13,14]` *may* use the same seed as `f[2,3]`.

Comment: Isn't this what happens by default? See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html), it says *"For parallel computations it is very advantageous to have a generator on each thread that produces random numbers independent from the generators on other threads. In Mathematica each thread used in a parallel computation will be given a unique index starting from zero (and typically going sequentially through $ProcessorCount) that will be used to give different seeds and generators on each thread."*

Comment: I want all the computation within a function to happen on the same kernel. If the function involves multiple ( say 10000) random draws then all should come from the same stream.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is `BlockRandom`.

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlockRandom.html),

```
BlockRandom[expr]
evaluates expr with all pseudorandom generators localized,
so that uses of SeedRandom, RandomInteger, and related functions
within the evaluation of expr do not affect subsequent pseudorandom sequences.
```

Then you might have:

```
f[a_, b_] := BlockRandom[{}, RandomReal[{a, b}]
```